# Android Gallery animated loading spinner while images are downloaded

Tags: android, animation, imageview, gallery

Hi i want to animate the imageViews in my Gallery (although i know its deprecated) while the image is beeing downloaded. It works with a crappy looking animation-set but I would love to have a rotating android-like progress indicator. I've been searching for a couple hours now and found nothing that fixes my problem.

```
// getView of my ImageAdapter for gallery
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{    
  ...
   if(image != null){
    //set the downloaded image and stop animation
    imageView.setAnimation(null);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
   }
   else{
    //display loading animation

     // this works - but looks crappy
     //R.drawable.loading is animation-set with 5 images
     //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading);
     //AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
     //anim.start();

    //this leads to my problem 
    //R.drawable.loading_circle is .png which looks like the android one
    //R.anim.rotate is infinite 360 degree rotation
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_circle); // wont work with .setImageResource() too
    imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(imageView.getContext(), R.anim.rotate));
   }
   ...
}
```

But this won't work as expected (I created an image which shows my Problem - but i cant post it - so here's a link http://s1.directupload.net/images/140807/kmws7pi2.png)...

- The animation only starts if the imageView of the Gallery contains an image (but then the animation should stop anyway)
- the animations are only moving with the imageView if it's empty

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the listview item layout where you placed image .. place progressbar and make progress bar (round) visible and imageview hide. When image is downloaded hide the progressbar and display imageview with downloaded image set.

Comment: its not that easy because i use a gallery not a horizontal listview or something similar... i cant (or dont know if its possible) set the imageView inside the gallery as a layout

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

1. create animantion.xml in drawable folder and paste the code having reference to your animating images

   ```
   <item    android:drawable="@drawable/app00000"    android:duration="300"/>
   <item    android:drawable="@drawable/app00001"    android:duration="300"/>
   <item    android:drawable="@drawable/app00002"    android:duration="300"/>
   <item    android:drawable="@drawable/app00003"    android:duration="300"/>
   <item    android:drawable="@drawable/app00004"    android:duration="300"/>
   ```

In your else statement use the below code

```
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);//animation.xml reference here
        final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

        if(frameAnimation.isRunning()){
                    frameAnimation.stop();
                }else{  
                    frameAnimation.stop();
                    frameAnimation.start();
                }
```

Comment: hi - this is excactly what i have and that works - but it looks crappy... what i want to have is that i set the "progress indicator" as a .png in the imageView an then start the rotate animation - which looks much smoother than the animation set...